# Adding Image to Title Page Background

Tags: graphics, margins, titles

all! I'm trying to add an image behind the text on my title page. I'm using the Fiction Novel template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fiction-novel/pjdthvgdtsfy), which uses the memoir class. Unfortunately, whenever I try to add an image to the title page, it pushes the title to the next page without the accompanying image. Furthermore, the image that I added, even if I've defined the height and width as \paperheight and \paperwidth, it still conforms to the margins set for each page. Ultimately, the question I need y'all's help with is the following: ***How do I add a full-page image with the centered title on top of it?*** I've included some of the relevant snippets below, but the rest can be accessed at the link provided.

```
% custom title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*\titleM{\begingroup
  \setlength\drop{0.15\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\HUGE\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textit\theauthor\par}
  \vfill
  {\Large\scshape\press}
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

...

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% the title page
\begin{vplace}[0.7]
\titleM
\end{vplace}
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `eso-pic`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newlength\drop
\newcommand*\titleM
  {%
    \begingroup
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*
      {%
        \AtPageLowerLeft
          {%
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
              {example-image-duck}%
          }%
      }%
    \setlength\drop{0.15\textheight}%
    \begin{center}%
    \vspace*{\drop}%
    \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
    {\HUGE\textsc\thetitle\par}%
    \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
    {\Large\textit\theauthor\par}%
    \vfill
    %{\Large\scshape\press}%
    \end{center}%
    \endgroup
  }

\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\date{Somewhen}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titleM
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]